# react fetching data array with setState is working but not with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetch data array with `hooks` but it throws an error. However, when using `setState` it will work.

I am getting the books data from `googleapis` like this:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

  const searchBook = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    request
      .get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes')
      .query({q:searchField})
      .then((data)=> {
        console.log(data.body.items)

        //with setState it works
        this.setState({books: [...data.body.items]})

        //with hooks it is not working
        setBooks([...data.body.items])
        console.log(books)

      })
  }
```

Using Hooks will throw an error `Objects are not valid as a React child`

Any idea how to make it work with `hooks`?

**Edited**

I added a link 
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-forest-9pstc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

For example, if I type `dog` in the input and click search, I see my `console.log(data.body.items)` but `console.log(books, "books")` is an empty array.

Comment: Hey kirimi, I think you are rendering an `object`. It will be great if you add the response or a link using Codesandbox or Codepen.

Comment: The error you get is thrown during rendering, not during setting of the value. Please add your rendering code (what is returned from the function you show us the content of).

Comment: @YashJoshi I will add a link thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting empty result in `console.log(books, "books")` because `setBooks` is an async function.

Try this.

```
const searchBook = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        request
          .get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes')
          .query({q:searchField})
          .then((data)=> {
            setBooks([...data.body.items])
          })
      }
```

**Live Example:**

[image: Edit adoring-almeida-59oys]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added a link it worked! but I notice that I have to click twice to update hooks. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Checking this issue

Comment: I have add the live example could you please try.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Your answer works!  but would like to know what is happening.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you were doing this

```js
setBooks([...data.body.items]);
```

instead of this

```js
setBooks(data.body.items);
```

Because you don't need to create a new array from the existing `data.body.items` which is already an array. So I tried it in the codesandbox you provided and that seems to fix the problem.